# How to parse csv file with comma in some fields

Tags: r, csv, sparklyr

I am using `Sparklyr`'s function `spark_read_csv` to parse a csv file into Spark.

I have a csv file but some of columns have comma as their value and they are separated by quotation marks:

Here is a snapshot of my data:

```
100005870186,B,C,01NOV05,1,0,1,0,23,5.5,217876.2,1,"BANK OF AMERICA, N.A.",5.5,"223,000.00",
```

As you can imagine, if I use `spark_read_csv()` to read in and comma is treated as delimiter, `"BANK OF AMERICA, N.A."` will be parsed into two fields so does `"223,000.00".` Is there a way to parse this correctly?

Comment: You need to remove the comma in "223,000.00" using a regular expression in some program.

Comment: Is it possible not to remove comma but parse it correctly?

Comment: I'll have to mull over it. Sucks you have such poorly formatted data

Comment: Try `spark_read_csv(sc,  ... , escape = "\,")` to escape the ",".